Вопрос по циклу while C#
Возникли некоторые вопросы относительно работы  цикла while на C# . Как я понимаю  ,он продолжается пока условие  верно .Написал код ,в котором есть значение 5  и в цикле  оно умножается сначала на 3 потом на 4 и выводит в косоль.

Вроде все работает , но в консоли почему то выводится также  отрицательное  значение.Разве он не должен перестать работать  после вывода значения 179159040?
Вывод отрицательного числа в данном случае  связан с тем , что при таком  умножении  возникает 2.14990848е9?


Текстовую информацию нужно вставлять текстом.

Вывод отрицательного числа вызван логикой вашего цикла - умножение и вывод производится после проверки на отрицательность. Или по-другому - сначала умножили и напечатали, только потом проверили...
А то, что вообще получается отрицательное число - обусловлено форматом целых знаковых 32-разрядных чисел, положительный диапазон которых ограничен значением 2^31-1
